# DDMS Not Showing Threads From Device

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I'd like to check for memory leaks in my Android app using the `DDMS` feature in `Eclipse`. When I launch an emulated device, the threads display properly for the emulated device, starting with 8600 and up.

However, when I connect my Droid to the PC, the device shows up just fine in DDMS. The logcat is generated correctly, and I can view the file structure. However, threads do not display. I get "no client selected" in the Threads pane, and there is no drop-down icon next to the device listing.

Do I need to change some particular setting in Eclipse? Is this maybe a driver issue?

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse Preferences (OSX) > Android > DDMS > check Thread Updates Enabled by Default

Add Android Device view to get device pan(e) noted above

Set android:debuggable=true (two g's) in app tag as noted above

Run your app in emulator

Select device in device pane

Click the update threads button

Enjoy

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have `android:debuggable="true"` in you `application tag` in the manifest file

Comment: The important thing for me here was to place `android:debuggable="true"` in the **application** tag. I'd placed it in a different tag (`manifest`) without paying attention. Placed correctly the thread shows up nicely under the device name in DDMS :-) Happy days !

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior. The issue is your **droid is not in debug** mode. Notice that in the `Devices` pane, beside the version number, `debug` is stated against the emulated device but not in the case of the droid.
From what I have found so far -  on the droid, only an app can be run in debug mode; and only this will be listed under your device in DDMS.

I don't know how to run(/boot) the entire droid in debug mode, or if it is possible. So far as it appears, there is no way to boot an entire real device in 'debug' more.

Answer (score 2):

Go to DDMS

Select device in device pan

Look at header of this pane. You can see update threads

You can see thread and updates from device

Answer (score 1):

If you use Intellij Idea like me - run monitor from tools-> android, other way Idea built in ADB conflict with ddms.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio : 
On the DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server) Screen:
Show View -> and then select the profiling view you need.