# DDMS (Android debug monitor) doesn't list processes on Galaxy S II

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, ddms, galaxy

I'm developing on a Samsung Galaxy S II using eclipse and the eclipse android plugin. This is not the first time I'm using DDMS on this computer or phone and everything used to work just fine.

Now, when I connect the device, DDMS shows it on the device list, LogCat shows output, I can even browse the file system, but clicking on the device does not show its process list.

I have tried restarting my computer, restarting the phone, turning debug mode off and on again, connecting it to another computer, checking the cable by connecting another device, all to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to list all the processes like I used to be able to, but I at least managed to show the process of the application I'm developing by setting `android:debuggable="true"` in the `application` element of the manifest, and by setting the `debug` property to `true` in the `default.properties` file.

Comment: On Sony Xperia Z, 4.1.2 OS adding android:debuggable="true" helped me, I can see it now. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Only a particular app being 'debugged' will show under a physical device.
Since unlike the emulator - an actual device does not run in `debug` mode.

If the app you wish to debug is not listed then make sure that it is:

1. a debug build
2. running on the device

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111467/483588

Answer (score 0):

1. `Settings` -> `Application` -> `Development` -> `USB Debug`: set ON , `Stay awake`: set ON
2. Replace other USB cables
3. Install Samsung ADB device interface for development (Composite ADB Interface)

Well, that's all I know.

Comment: Galaxy S II doesn't have the 'stay awake' option. The other advices didn't help either :/ Thanks though.

Comment: So, why the answer is accepted if it doesn't solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For whom ever gets here, I solved the problem doing what @Fenix Voltres said above, and changed the AndroidManifest flag to android:debuggable="true".

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 instances of eclipse open this could cause the problem.

close the other instances and try again.